# typoscript add each 4th element a div

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I hav ethe following typoscript script which prints elements into my page.

```
lib.unterseiten = CONTENT
lib.unterseiten {
  table = pages
  select {
    pidInList.field = 10
    orderBy = sorting
  }
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj.wrap = <div class='col-md-3'>|</div>
  renderObj {
    10 = TEXT
    10.field = title
    10.wrap = <h2>|</h2>
    20 = CONTENT
    20 {
      table = tt_content
      select {
        pidInList.field = uid
        orderBy = sorting
      }
      renderObj = COA
      renderObj {

        #Bild auslesen
        30 = FILES
        30 {
          maxItems = 1
          references {
            table = tt_content
            uid.data = field:uid
            fieldName = image
            maxItems = 1
         }

         renderObj = IMAGE
         renderObj.file.import.data = file:current:uid
         renderObj.file.treatIdAsReference = 1
         renderObj.wrap = <div class="thumbnail bild">|</div>
          renderObj.stdWrap.maxItems = 1
      }
        40 = TEXT
        40.value = Mehr Infos
        40.typolink.ATagParams = class="btn btn-primary"
        40.typolink.parameter.data  = field:pid
      }
    }

  }
}

page.20.marks.kumulierterInhalt  < lib.unterseiten
```

Is it possible to add after each 4th element a div?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

```
lib.unterseiten = CONTENT
lib.unterseiten {
  table = pages
  select {
    pidInList.field = 10
    orderBy = sorting
  }
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj.wrap = <div class='col-md-3'>|</div>
  renderObj {
    10 = TEXT
    10.field = title
    10.wrap = <h2>|</h2>
    20 = CONTENT
    20 {
      table = tt_content
      select {
        pidInList.field = uid
        orderBy = sorting
      }
      renderObj = COA
      renderObj {

        #Bild auslesen
        30 = FILES
        30 {
          maxItems = 1
          references {
            table = tt_content
            uid.data = field:uid
            fieldName = image
            maxItems = 1
         }

         renderObj = IMAGE
         renderObj.file.import.data = file:current:uid
         renderObj.file.treatIdAsReference = 1
         renderObj.wrap = <div class="thumbnail bild">|</div>
          renderObj.stdWrap.maxItems = 1
      }
        40 = TEXT
        40.value = Mehr Infos
        40.typolink.ATagParams = class="btn btn-primary"
        40.typolink.parameter.data  = field:pid
      }
    }
     99 = TEXT
     99.value = ###SEPARATOR###
  }


   stdWrap {
        split {
            token = ###SEPARATOR###
            cObjNum = |*| 1 || 1 || 1 || 2 |*|

            1.current = 1

            2.current = 1
            2.wrap = | <br><br><hr class="separatorline" />
        }
    }

}

page.20.marks.kumulierterInhalt  < lib.unterseiten
```

Comment: i would strongly recommend to use dataProcessing with MenuProcessor. Then you could add an extra field on the pages table and add the image there. Then on your fluid you could just have a condition, that if the page has an image/icon then it should render it

Answer (score 1):

wrapping an iteration over an array is typically done with `optionsplit` in typoscript.
wrapping each 4th element would be:

```
|*| || || || |<div>...</div> |*|
```

but trying to do so with `renderObj` will result in repetition of the first wrap as each renderObj has it's own context, starting the `optionsplit` anew.

a workaround would be:
wrap each element with a special pattern like: `###SEPARATOR###` and split the resulting string to wrap it up again.

```
lib.unterseiten {
    renderObj {
        wrap = <div class='col-md-3'>|</div>###SEPARATOR###
        : 
        :
        #99 = TEXT
        #99.value = ###SEPARATOR###
    }
    stdWrap {
        split {
            token = ###SEPARATOR###
            cObjNum = |*| 1 || 1 || 1 || 2 |*|

            1.current = 1

            2.current = 1
            2.wrap = |<div>...</div>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thats really close to that what I want. But the separator is now not atfer the 4th element, its inside the 4th element

Comment: Maybe you added the separator and following split to the inner renderObj ?

Comment: any further hints?

Comment: be aware that you have `lib.unterseiten.renderObj.wrap = <div class='col-md-3'>|</div>` which of course is around `lib.unterseiten.renderObj.99`. probably best solution is to add the marker to this wrap: `lib.unterseiten.renderObj.wrap = <div class='col-md-3'>|</div>###SEPARATOR###`